# Problems to open a serial port with fopen php

Tags: windows, php, serial-port

well i'm trying to open a serial port using fopen php but i always get

Warning: fopen(COM5) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in

but if i try to open a non-exists com port, it show:

Warning: fopen(COM6) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Probably i'm missing something. someone could tell me it?

Comment: Check http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/archive/index.php/t-10323067.html

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure you can't open a COM port with fopen in Windows, you have to use [dio](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php)

Comment: but i can open com1 with fopen. this com5 is from my usb 3g modem, it's a virtual serial port.